# Como obter valor de um campo RadioButton em JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Não consigo obter o `value` do meu campo `RadioButton`

```
@Html.Label("Ativo")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(v => v.Ativo,"S", new { name="ativo"})
@Html.Label("Inativo")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(v => v.Ativo,"N", new { name="ativo"})

<script>
function ObterValues() {
 var radioButton =  $('input:radio[name^=ativo]:checked').val();  
 console.log(radioButton);
}
 </script>
```

Comment: $('input[type="radio"][name="ativo"]:checked').val(); Tente assim; OBS: NÃO TESTEI

Answer (score 2):

O problema aqui está na sintaxe do MVC.
Para sobrescrever o atributo `name` do Html, é preciso usar a propriedade `@Name` (com N maisculo).

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WPkfVw)

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name="Ativo")]
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new SampleViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head> 
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Ativo")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(v => v.Ativo,"S", new { @Name="ativo"})
                @Html.Label("Inativo")
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(v => v.Ativo,"N", new { @Name="ativo"})
            </div>
        }
        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){           
                var ativo = $("input:radio[name='ativo']");
                function onAtivoClick() {
                    var value =  ativo.filter(":checked").val();
                    console.log(value);
                }                   
                ativo.click(onAtivoClick);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: bLZ !! obtive sucesso!! OBg